# Display multidimensional array using foreach and for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
for(int $i=0; $i<count($lists["item_collection"]["entries"]); $i++){
        foreach($lists['item_collection']['entries'] as $list) 
        {
            $print['file_name'] = $list[$i]['name'];
            $print['file_id'] = $list[$i]['id'];
            $print['file_type'] = $list[$i]['type'];

            array_push($content,$print);
        }
    }
```

i am trying to get the name,type,id of the file array
but i only get the first one
so i tried to for loop it
but it doesn't work.
am i doing this right?

Comment: Just to be clear, what language is this?  PHP, correct?

Comment: Please try to use the `yield` keyword and a generating method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do it inside a for loop, just:

```
foreach($lists["item_collection"]["entries"] as $key => $val){

    $print['file_name'] = $val['name'];
    $print['file_id'] = $val['id'];
    $print['file_type'] = $val['type'];

    array_push($content,$print);

}
```

Comment: welcome, I up vote your question. keep posting! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I do not tested it

```
foreach($lists["item_collection"]["entries"] as $v){
     foreach($v as $val){  
         $print['file_name'] = $val['name'];
        $print['file_id'] = $val['id'];
        $print['file_type'] = $val['type'];
        array_push($content,$print);
     }

}
```